# how to call my webservice from url

Tags: web-services, rest, url, post

I have an endpoint to my REST webservice like this:

```
http://www.example.com/example_endpoint/user
```

and the content-type is: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

And I want to call it by url with the parameters:

```
firstname=firstname_test
lastname=lastname_test
pass=123
```

I'm calling like this, but I get no results:

```
http://www.example.com/example_endpoint/user?firstname=firstname_test&lastname=lastname_test&pass=123
```

How should I call the webservice???

Comment: Is your webservice expecting parameters and their corresponding values sent via `GET`?

Comment: yes, its expecting parameters but it's suppoused to be sent via `POST`

Comment: Ok; when you send those parameters in the URL, they're being sent via `GET`, not `POST`. To send via `POST` you'll need to send them using an HTML `form`, or another programmatic alternative. I would just search for `send post to web service`, that should point you in the right direction.